# Why macros with cell.value stop work and give me back error 2015?

Tags: excel

```
 Sub ProbationEmailGeneral()
Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range
```

`Set r = Range("CI:CI")


For Each cell In r

    If cell.Value = Date Then

        Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
        Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
        Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

        Email_Subject = "TEXT"
        Email_Send_From = "email"
        Email_Send_To = "email"
        Email_Cc = ""
        Email_Bcc = ""
        Email_Body = "TEXT"

        On Error GoTo debugs
        Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
        With Mail_Single
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_Send_To
        .cc = Email_Cc
        .BCC = Email_Bcc
        .Body = Email_Body
        .send
        End With

    End If

Next


Exit Sub`

debugs:
        If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

This is code. yesterday it works without problem but when I try to start it todat it give me back an error 2015 and make this line "If cell.Value = Date Then" yellow.

Comment: You most likely have a `#VALUE!` error value in your cells.

Comment: @Dragomir Dragomirov  What are `Range("CI:CI")` sample values and How they relate to `If cell.Value = Date Then` code line.

Comment: Thank you to Rory. I found cell with #Value! error and after delete it everything works.